# Creating Dynamically changing icons in status bar and status notifications(ongoing), Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-notifications

I want to create dynamically changing/animating icons which will show up in statusbar and notifications in android.
Below are some examples that can clarify what I want :

[image]

[image]

In above example 2nd icon in left side of status bar changes with time ! I want to add similar functionality in my app but I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Also please tell me what should be the dimensions of the image icon that I should make ?

Comment: Do you see my answer? is it helpful?

Comment: yeah obviously I saw your answer, and It helped me, Sorry i forgot to mark it correct !